# Android studio setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); is not working even my second activity name activity_login is presenr in layout folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

[udio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJBVA.png)

```
package com.example.helppido;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
   }
}
```

Comment: just restart your android studio or else invalidate chaches/Restart from File

Answer (score 0):

Please change this import `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;` to 
`import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`